# Would EdDSA be broken by replacing H(R, A, M) with H(A, M)?

Tags: schnorr-signature, threshold-cryptography, eddsa

An EdDSA signature is (R, S) where R = r*B and S = r + H(R, A, M)*s. Notation from Wikipedia [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA).

Given that the hash function H, is indeed collision-resistant, would using S = r + H(A, M)*s be a secure variant?

In the original [EdDSA paper](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/papers.html), the authors mention the need for R to protect the signature scheme in case the hash function is *not* collision-resistant. To me, it indicates that the scheme could possibly be secure even when R is left out from the hash function input.

The reason I ask (in case it is of interest) is that using H(A, M) would be more *threshold-friendly*. Threshold signatures with that modification in place could be done using 1 round instead of 2 rounds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is assuming you are not removing the private key $a$ from the computation of $S$, and instead actually meant what is said in the title of the question:

> $S = r + a H(A, M)$

Removing $a$ from the computation would be terrible.

---

The first issue that comes to mind is **malleability**, on top of collision resistance.

The signature process for EdDSA actually goes as follows:

> Input: message $M$, secret key bits $(h_0, h_1, \ldots, h_{2b-1})$,
> basepoint $B$  and public key point $A$
>
> 1. $a \gets 2^{b-2} + \sum_{3 \leq i \leq b-3} 2^i h_i$
> 2. $h \gets H(h_b,\ldots,h_{2b-1},M)$
> 3. $r \gets h\mod \ell$
> 4. $R \gets r\cdot B$
> 5. $h \gets H(R, A, M)$
> 6. $S \gets (r + a h) \mod \ell$
>
> Return: $(R,S)$

As you can see, if you do not include the value $R$ in the hash $h$, the value $S \gets (r + a h) \mod \ell$ can easily be modified in a way that would allow to produce new signatures for the same message:

1. pick a random $k$
2. compute the point $R' = R + k\cdot B$
3. compute the value $S' = S + k \bmod \ell$

And you now have a new, different signature $(R', S')$ for the same public key $A$ that will verify for the message $M$.
This is possible because the value $r$ behind computed with the secret key, it is not meant to be public and is not necessary for verification. This property was used in a [fault attack in 2017](https://www.romailler.ch/ddl/10.1109_FDTC.2017.12_eddsa.pdf).

[Malleability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malleability_(cryptography)) is not necessarily unwanted in cryptographic scheme, but is often frowned upon since it can very easily lead to issue with implementations.

Threshold cryptography is rough and full of dangers, and I wouldn't advise coming up with a malleable scheme as these [have already proven to cause issue with threshold schemes](https://medium.com/zengo/baby-sharks-a3b9ceb4efe0).

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for assuming a correcting of the question. Yes, I did not intend to remove the secret key!

Comment: @Lery  I see malleability, I did not even think of it, thank you. That alone would not make it broken it as someone still cannot forge a signature for a message that the owner of key has not signed. It makes the scheme resistant to existential forgery (cannot forge a valid signature on message not signed by the owner) but not to strong existential forgery (can produce a valid signature of message that the owner has not produced)

Answer (score 6):

> would using S = r + H(A, M) be a secure variant?

Actually, it would become trivial to generate a signature for an abitrary message with just the public key.

The verification check would be:

$$2^h s G = 2^h R + 2^h H(A, M) A$$

where $h$ is the curve cofactor, $G$ is the curve generator, $A$ is the public key, $M$ is the message and $(R, s)$ is the signature.

So, what the attacker ould do is pick an arbitrary $s$ and try to solve:

$$2^h sG - 2^h H(A, M)A = 2^h R$$

Everything on the right side is known, and so it's easy to find an $R$ that satisfies this ($sG - H(A, M)A$ is one solution)

Comment: Oh my, I got carried away, because indeed if one is removing $a$ altogether, then it's completely broken.

Comment: Sorry about the mistake. Of course, the secret scalar, s, must of course be included. I did a quick edit of the question. My 2-year old is disturbing me, so I hope I got it right now.

Comment: @FransLundberg: same answer; to verify, just write out the verification condition, and see if you can solve for $R$ (given everything else is known)